# How to get an implementation of fmt::Debug for a Vec of dyn Trait objects?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait MyTrait of which all implementations could implement fmt::Debug.
I have a struct MyStruct that contains a `Vec<Rc<dyn MyTrait>>`.
How do I implement fmt::Debug for MyStruct?

My first idea was to just implement Debug for MyStruct manually but that seems very wrong, considering that only the implementation of Debug of the MyTrait objects could vary.

Logically I should be able to require MyTrait to "include" (in Java terms that would be interface inheritance) Debug and then simply derive Debug for MyStruct automatically.
But how would I achieve this? I haven't found anything to that effect in the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `Debug` as a [supertrait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait) of `MyTrait`:

```
trait MyTrait: std::fmt::Debug {...}
```

Some people call this feature "trait inheritance", but a supertrait is not much like a base class in languages that support class inheritance. It's really just a *constraint* on implementors of `MyTrait`: "If you implement `MyTrait`, you have to implement `Debug` too." Since `dyn MyTrait` is a type that implements `MyTrait`, it too has its own (automatically generated) `Debug` implementation, which just defers to the `Debug` for the concrete type.

However, you cannot [upcast a trait object to a supertrait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait), at least not without some extra work.

Comment: Regarding similarity to inheritance, I agree with everything you said, with an additional remark. While supertrait is a constraint for implementors, it's a guarantee for _users_ of the trait: "by requring `MyTrait` you get `Debug` for free". This is where the parallels with inheritance can be drawn, and in this case the effect is just what the OP expected - being able to ["simply derive `Debug`"](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a02a2d7f0f7fce6e7cd12bb86c855f3).